# Are these two equivalent?

Tags: java

Do both of these have the same result? If so I'm just confused on why you don't have to have an else statement returning `inventoryList.size();` on the first piece of code because if the if statement is true won't it return `0` and `inventoryList.size();`?

```
public int numItems() {
    if (inventoryList.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return inventoryList.size();
}
```

And

```
public int numItems()   {
  if (inventoryList.size() != 0)  {
     return inventoryList.size();
  }
  else  {
     return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't even need those checks in the first place.

Comment: the implementation of "isEmpty()" is `public boolean isEmpty() { return size == 0; }`, but to be honest, you could just use `inventoryList.size()` in all circumstances here.

Comment: This is the kind of question that the compiler is happy to answer for you. Did you ask it?

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you are trying to wrap the **inventoryList.size()** method?   You should just go

```
public int numItems() { return inventoryList.size(); }
```

What doesn't that do that you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent. In either case you can skip the else, since you return from the consequent of your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

When a return statement is executed, that method stops there and no more code is executed.
Therefore these two functions are equal.

Answer (score 0):

No the return statement exits out of the function. Think of it like a go to statement which is what is happening behind the scenes.